# Jenkins Uploading file from local machine to confluence REST API - Groovy

Tags: groovy, confluence, confluence-rest-api

So I am trying to work on a groovy script within Jenkins that takes a file from local machine and pushes to a confluence page.

I can't seem to find any documentation for this.

I found this code, and I'm new to groovy so just wanted to make sure I'm on the correct track. I added some comments to my understanding if someone could clarify what they mean that would be awesome, and let me know if I am on the right track?

```
def server = new XMLRPCServerProxy("http://confluence:8090/rpc/xmlrpc")//Here we would have the link to our confluence server
    def spaceKey = "Area" // not sure what spaceKey means
    def pageTitel = "FileUpload"//The title of the page we are uploading to
    def fileName  = "D:\\datamodel.pdf"//the file path 
    def contentType = "application/pdf"//file extensions
    def token = server.confluence2.login("UserName" , "Password")//confluence login credientials
    def page  = server.confluence2.getPage(token, spaceKey, pageTitel)//not sure
    def file = new File (fileName)
    server.confluence2.addAttachment( token, page.id, [ fileName: file.name, contentType:contentType ], file.bytes )
```

Comment: You are using XMLRPC which is deprecated, I would recommend you to take a look at rest API and send via REST call

Answer (score 0):

i'm work with the same task, but find only case with **curl**. It's work, but this is not groovy.